# ip6tables does not filter fragmented packets

Tags: iptables, ipv6

My final goal is to block all TCP IPv6 fragments with a specified destination IPv6 address (lets say it is one of google.com addresses `2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79`).

This traffic is forwarded by host from the application in docker container to the next router available over upstream interface (lets say it is `eth0`).

The issue is that rules like
`ip6tables -t filter -A FORWARD -d 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79/128  -o eth0 -m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft -j DROP`
or
`ip6tables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79/128  -o eth0 -m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft -j DROP`
or using module `frag` does not filter fragmented packets:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-11-241:/# sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 -Q out ip6 host 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79
...
15:53:31.088597 IP6 2600:1f16:c97:7a02:f52b:8bb4:1751:e72a > 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79: frag (0|104) 37292 > 443: Flags [P.], seq 1428:1500, ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 751022009 ecr 3180988502], length 72
...
```

Investigation shows that that ip6tables and tcpdump here see a bit different picture of what happens with packets:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-11-241:/# sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 -Q out ip6 host 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79
...
15:53:31.088278 IP6 2600:1f16:c97:7a02:f52b:8bb4:1751:e72a.37292 > 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79.443: Flags [.], ack 2909720068, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 751022009 ecr 3180988502], length 0
15:53:31.088597 IP6 2600:1f16:c97:7a02:f52b:8bb4:1751:e72a > 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79: frag (0|104) 37292 > 443: Flags [P.], seq 1428:1500, ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 751022009 ecr 3180988502], length 72
15:53:31.088781 IP6 2600:1f16:c97:7a02:f52b:8bb4:1751:e72a.37292 > 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79.443: Flags [.], seq 0:1378, ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 751022009 ecr 3180988502], length 1378
15:53:31.088798 IP6 2600:1f16:c97:7a02:f52b:8bb4:1751:e72a.37292 > 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79.443: Flags [P.], seq 1378:1500, ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 751022009 ecr 3180988502], length 122
15:53:31.089023 IP6 2600:1f16:c97:7a02:f52b:8bb4:1751:e72a.37292 > 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79.443: Flags [F.], seq 1500, ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 751022010 ecr 3180988502], length 0

# dmesg after enabling logging with sudo ip6tables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::79/128 -o eth0 -j LOG:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-11-241:~$ sudo dmesg -T
...
# packet #1, looks good
[Mon Nov 27 15:53:33 2023] IN=docker0 OUT=eth0 PHYSIN=veth9c34169 MAC=02:42:49:39:59:c0:02:42:ac:11:00:02:86:dd SRC=fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0242:ac11:0002 DST=2a00:1450:4010:0c0e:0000:0000:0000:0079 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=63 FLOWLBL=191995 PROTO=TCP SPT=37292 DPT=443 WINDOW=507 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
# packet #2, this one is unexpected 
[Mon Nov 27 15:53:33 2023] IN=docker0 OUT=eth0 PHYSIN=veth9c34169 MAC=02:42:49:39:59:c0:02:42:ac:11:00:02:86:dd SRC=fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0242:ac11:0002 DST=2a00:1450:4010:0c0e:0000:0000:0000:0079 LEN=1572 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=63 FLOWLBL=191995 PROTO=TCP SPT=37292 DPT=443 WINDOW=507 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
# packet #3, as well as this one
[Mon Nov 27 15:53:33 2023] IN=docker0 OUT=eth0 PHYSIN=veth9c34169 MAC=02:42:49:39:59:c0:02:42:ac:11:00:02:86:dd SRC=fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0242:ac11:0002 DST=2a00:1450:4010:0c0e:0000:0000:0000:0079 LEN=1572 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=63 FLOWLBL=191995 PROTO=TCP SPT=37292 DPT=443 WINDOW=507 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
# packet #4, looks good
[Mon Nov 27 15:53:33 2023] IN=docker0 OUT=eth0 PHYSIN=veth9c34169 MAC=02:42:49:39:59:c0:02:42:ac:11:00:02:86:dd SRC=fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0242:ac11:0002 DST=2a00:1450:4010:0c0e:0000:0000:0000:0079 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=63 FLOWLBL=191995 PROTO=TCP SPT=37292 DPT=443 WINDOW=507 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
...
```

Some black magic happens with packets #2 and #3 logged by netfilter with length 1572.

First of all packet #2. In reality client sends two ipv6 packets:

- first one is length of 1500 (1428 + 32 + 40)
- last one is length of 104 (32 + 32 + 40)

Fist one is dropped by the host since it bigger than mtu of 1450 other one is forwarded with atomic ipv6 fragment. netfilter thinks that **it was one packet len of 1572!**

Then packet #3. Client after getting ICMPv6 TOO_BIG form router, form new 2 packets:

- first one is length of 1450 (1378 + 32 + 40)
- another one is length of 194 (122 + 32 + 40)

Now both packets pass MTU so they are forwarded, and are in tcpdump output. However netfilter consider it **as one packet length of 1572!**

It seems that netfilter works with aggregated packets (TSO? GSO?) and simply does not see IPv6 fragment header. Is there any explanation to this behavior? How can I filter actual packets sent by host?

UPD1: Disabling TSO (tcp-segmentation-offload) *inside container* makes netfilter in root netns see two packets with correct sizes instead of one packet length of 1572 in both cases. Also, kernel does not create atomic ipv6 fragment in the first case. However, original question is still relevant.

Comment: The extension `ipv6header` is able to test for a fragmented ipv6 header, not for the entire ipv6 package. A package becomes fragmented when its datagram size is larger than MTU of the network interface.

Comment: "The extension ipv6header is able to test for a fragmented ipv6 header, not for the entire ipv6 package." - So iptables work with ipv6 headers, not ipv6 packets? Tbh this sound a bit strange for me.

Comment: "A package becomes fragmented when its datagram size is larger than MTU of the network interface." - In general yes, but there is corner cases when not only datagrams fragmented, and not only when they are bigger than destination MTU: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.200/source/net/ipv6/ip6_output.c#L181

Comment: No, iptables works with the entire ip packages, but its extension ipv6header only tests for the header of an ipv6 package, thus the name ipv6header.

Comment: Ok, so when a ipv6 *packet* that have ipv6 *fragment* header passes some iptables chain, `-m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft` should match such packet, right?

Comment: Yes, it should match. https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/iptables-extensions.html , https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ipv6-fragmentation-header/ , https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40242/when-do-ip-packets-get-reassembled-if-fragmentation-occurs-in-a-tunnel

Comment: Well, the original question is just exactly about reasons, why `-m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft` does not work on ipv6 packet with fragmented ipv6 header.

Comment: The logical answer to this is, that it's working, but the remaining setup of your iptable has a "bug". I would suspect the `-A`, which most likely should be more an `-I`. https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables